# Create N animated objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, delay, intervals

I want to create a number of hidden objects via jQuery,
that (once all created) slideDown() sequentially, one by one.
I don't want the second object to wait for the first to complete
the entire slideDown(), but it needs a certain delay.

The (not working) code i have is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var i = 3;

    var AnimFunc = function() {

        $('#container').append('<div id="elem_' + i + '>' + i + '</div>').hide().slideDown();
        --i;
        i == 0 ? clearInterval(startAnim) : null; // clear interval to prevent infinite loop

    }

    startAnim = setInterval(AnimFunc, 500); // 500 delay between slideDowns.

});
```

I guess it should even be possible with a do/while without the setInterval and clearInterval.

I hope my question is clear and someone will be able to help me.

Thanks,
Knal

Comment: Can I just say: `if (i===0) clearInterval(startAnim);` is both easier to read and less typing than your ternary operator `? :` equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I get what your trying to do, but maybe it's something like this:

```
var objectNumb = 10,
    speed = 1500;

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i=objectNumb; i>=1; i--) {
        $('#container').append('<div id="elem_'+i+'">'+i+'</div>').hide().delay(speed).slideDown(speed);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/vUsjY/1/)

Comment: @nnnnnn; Thanks, you're absolutely right. To me, js is like a foreign language; ok to read, but hard to write. Thanks!

@ali youhannaei; Thanks for the heads up, a sloppy copy/paste/edit of mine.

@adeneo; Nailed it! Exactly what i needed! Thanks.

Thank you guys, great help!

Comment: Hmm, kind of cheered too early! All divs wait for the previous one to finish animating before they start. I would like to be able to (for instance) make the animation 5 secs per div, but start every new div 1 sec after the previous. In practice, this would mean div #6 would start exactly when #1 has finished. Thanks again guys! –

Comment: I hope it's clear what i mean, i'd really like this certain feature for this solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem is my code, written in a hurry it seems it now hides and slides down the container and not the elements. This is a bit tricky, but something like [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vUsjY/2/) should help you out. You will probably have to fiddle with positions and timers to get it right.

Comment: Great! That's exactly it! I'll have to take a better look at the code to see why it does what it does, but the effect is  what i intended!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

when you generate the id you lose the double quotation after adding i 
use this:  ' + i + ' "